# CheckBoxList Problem

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkboxlist

I have a checkboxlist in C# that is databound from the database. What I would like to do is display an icon on the right side after the text for each of the checkboxlist items. Each icon needs to be different though. Thanks for your help!

Comment: What help? All I can read from your question is how you would like it to be displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" runat="server"
DataSourceID="dataSourceID"
DataTextField="dataTextField"
DataValueField="dataTextValue"
OnDataBound="CheckBoxList1_DataBound">
</asp:CheckBoxList>

protected void CheckBoxList1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var checkBox = sender as CheckBoxList;
    if(checkBox != null)
    {
        foreach (ListItem listItem in checkBox.Items)
        {
            listItem.Text = string.Format("{0}<img src='{1}' />", listItem.Text, GetImageFor(listItem.Text));
        }
    }

}

private string GetImageFor(string text)
{
    // return image url for check box based on text.

    if(text.Equals("Banana")) return "banana.gif";
    ...
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

We've used an approach that is fairly similar, but moves the code to the object model to simplify implementation on multiple pages.

Read-only property in the object code (C#):

```
public string chk_item_html { get { return item_name + string.Format("<img src='item{0}.png' />", item_id); } }
```

And then in the asp:CheckBoxList, you simply set DataTextField = "chk_item_html"

Answer (score 0):

You can apply a css class to each data bound checkbox and display an icon with CSS